# using php within setTimeout in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have an issue using my php code within the javascript function setTimeout. The code is in a php file, but instead of acting like it should and waiting the five minutes to send the user to the index page of my website, it just does it instantly. Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function() { <?php header( 'Location: /index.html' ); ?> }, 300000);
</script>
```

Comment: You can't set headers anywhere but the start of your PHP page.

Comment: The header was mainly for example purposes, I plan on using much more complicated php code in that snippet. I just thought as an example I would just use a simple php function to ask my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is because the PHP Code first gets executed, because it is server-side. So you would have to modify your code:

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function() { window.location.href='/index.html'  }, 300000);
</script>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make sure the php is not executed first, and it does truly wait until the correct time, because I need to use php in this code snippet (not for the redirection, but for other things as well)

Comment: @Twisterz : no.. you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how javascript and php works. PHP gets executed on the server, javascript on the client. By the time the browser gets to execute javascript, PHP is completely out of the picture.

Comment: @Twisterz the PHP will be executed before the page even gets to the browser.